# Xcode project crashes on load devices

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this error after compiling and running on  iPhone devices.  I just get a black screen with this in the output in xcode.

I have no idea where to start debugging this.

**Error:**

```
CrashReporter: initialized
CrashReporter: saved pending crash report.
CrashReporter: saved copy of pending crash report.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
[XR] Discovering subsystems at path /var/containers/Bundle/Application/14FDCF0D-4899-49BC-99C6-FB2AC69BDADB/gorilaTe.app/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A8 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2019.2.2f1 (ab112815d860)
CrashReporter: Successfully deleted pending crash report after sending it: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/07606C75-E871-488E-B61E-39915445DFBD/Library/Caches/CrashReports/crash-pending.plcrash
```